# Windows HTTP to HTTPs or Secure Proxy

Tags: windows, server, proxy, ssl, secure

I have a program that serves pages via http (without SSL) on windows.
I want to make that secure if it's possible.

*I tried to write my own middle-ware but I failed. It worked but it can't handle web-sockets.*
Here is my code if anyone wants something simpler: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537388/custom-https-server-websocket-dont-work)

If anyone can recommend a program that **runs on Windows** and can **act as a proxy server**, serves pages **via SSL** and supports **POST requests** and **Web-Sockets**.

Thanks. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my proplem:
I use [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) as a proxy server.

Here is my conf file:

```
worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;

    #https proxy server
    server {
        listen               443 ssl;
        server_name          localhost;
        ssl_certificate      ../ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  ../ssl/private.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:80/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }

        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80/$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [nginx Proxy Manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/), it's nginx packaged with a nice UI to help manage it. (no more manual restarts of nginx :))